# how to limit the draggable area for columnchooser popup to jqgrid table only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have jqgrid table with columnchooser pop-up, the default behaviour of pop-up is draggable in anywhere of the screen. I want to restrict the draggable area to jqgrid table only. how to acheive this help me on this.

Comment: See this link
http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/9982/

Comment: Maybe add something like the code provided by @Nishant123 in the comment to the question, so we can easily see where you are, where one might help?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tyanai/ngm5rhgp/ see this demo u will get idea what exactly i need.